# Ajax form upload doesn't work on iOS

Tags: php, jquery, ios, ajax

I've got simple file upload form. Form works on desktop PC/Mac but doesn't work on iOS devices.
On submit event I make call like this:

```
var form_data = new FormData(this);
$.ajax({ 
    url: "api/register",
    method: "POST",
    type: "POST",
    headers: {
        "cache-control": "no-cache"
    },
    cache: false,
    data: form_data,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    async: true
}).success(function (res) { 


    alert ('uploaded');

}).error(function (res) {

    alert('not uploaded')
});
```

After 60 seconds error is returned nad I get 'not uploaded' alert.

Comment: Does it happen on safari or all browsers on iOS device? and what is the iOS version?

Comment: what jquery version are you using?

Comment: It happens on all browsers. iOS 11.3.1. jQuery 1.12.4.

Comment: Did you ever get a resolution?